# How to hide keyboard while open the drawer

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to hide the keyboard when I open the drawer but when I run the app it just opens the drawer without dismissing the keyboard. here is my code

```
useLayoutEffect(() => {

        navigation.setOptions({
            headerTitleAlign:'center',
            headerLeft:() =>(
                /*open drawer and dismiss keyboard*/
                <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() =>{Keyboard.dismiss;navigation.openDrawer()}}>
                    <View style={styles.menuIcon}>
                        <MaterialIcon name="menu" size={30} />
                    </View>
                </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
            ),
```

how can I do to fix it?

Comment: It should be `Keyboard.dismiss()` instead of `Keyboard.dismiss`

Comment: @JavascriptHuppTechnologies thank u very much

Answer (score 1):

`dismiss` is a method. You have to call it like this :

```
Keyboard.dismiss();
```

So, change you code with the following :

```js
useLayoutEffect(() => {
  navigation.setOptions({
    headerTitleAlign:'center',
    headerLeft:() =>(
      /*open drawer and dismiss keyboard*/
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        onPress={() =>{
          Keyboard.dismiss(); //Call it
          navigation.openDrawer()
        }}
      >
        <View style={styles.menuIcon}>
            <MaterialIcon name="menu" size={30} />
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    ),
  })
})
```

More detail is [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboard#dismiss)